# getScaledFrameAtTime() not 100% returning bitmaps with input sizes

Tags: android

On API 27, I tried to extract frames from selected video with `getScaledFrameAtTime()`, one in a series of threads/runnables. Here is the code snippet (in one thread per timestamp):

```
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(uri);
bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getScaledFrameAtTime(timeStamp * 1000,
                        MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST,
                        224,
                        224);
```

But sometimes I got bitmaps with width of only 126.
What happened? How to prevent and deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

> This method finds a representative frame close to the given time position by considering the given option if possible, and returns it as a bitmap with same aspect ratio as the source while scaling it so that it fits into the desired size of dst_width by dst_height.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#getScaledFrameAtTime(long,%20int,%20int,%20int)

It tries to maintain the original's aspect ratio, using `dst_width` and `dst_height` as maximums.